# Infimum and supremum problems

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

I have problem with finding inf and sup of sets:

$$ A=\left\{ n\in N:\quad 2(-1)^{n+1}+(-1)^{n(n+1)/2} \left(2+\frac{3}{n}\right) \right\}$$

$$ B=\left\{ n\in N: \quad \frac{n-1}{n+1}\cos{\frac{2\pi n}{3}} \right\}$$

and solution in my textbook argue that sets $A,B$ can be rewritten as

$\displaystyle  A = \{-3,-\frac{11}{2},5\} \cup \{\frac{3}{4k},-\frac{3}{4k+1},-4-\frac{3}{4k+2},4+\frac{3}{4k+3}\} $

$\displaystyle  B = \{\frac{3k-1}{3k+1},-\frac{3k-2}{6k},-\frac{3k-3}{2(3k-1)}\}$ where $k \in N$

Could you explain me this transition? Because I don't get it

Comment: for first, first three terms are written by putting $n=1,2,3$ then afterwards use the fact that every $n$ can be written as $4k$ or $4k+1$ or $4k+2$ or $4k+3$ and for second use 3 instead of 4

Comment: OK thanks but I wonder how should I notice that I have to use $4k,4k+1,...$ or $3k,3k+1...$ Lets take these two above sets what tells you to do this particular substituion

Comment: first of all see that there are 4 type of terms in $A$ involving $4k,4k+1,4k+2,4k+3$ this implies we're putting $n$ in multiple of 4, same goes with $B$

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, since in $B$ we have terms $n-1,n,n+1$ thus we input $n$ in multiple of $3$ but I don't see it in $A$ or my way of thinking is bad ?

Comment: look at the term $\displaystyle \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ it takes values 1,3,6,10,15,21,... of the form $4k,4k+1,4k+2,4k+3$